# Azure Blob Container file download

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I need to download CSV file from Azure Storage Account, Are there any ways to download the file(CSV) using java SDK or rest API? what API's need to be used?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/blob/BasicExample.java#L86 , this link shall help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Azure Storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java#download-blobs) for java . To download a file, you just need to use the class CloudBlockBlob which should look like,

```
// Download the blob to a local file
// Append the string "DOWNLOAD" before the .txt extension so that you can see both files.
String downloadFileName = fileName.replace(".txt", "DOWNLOAD.txt");
File downloadedFile = new File(localPath + downloadFileName);

System.out.println("\nDownloading blob to\n\t " + localPath + downloadFileName);

blobClient.downloadToFile(localPath + downloadFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to get a connection string also from java SDK using tenant id,Client Id, Application Id?

Comment: connection string for what?

Comment: For creating blob client

Comment: I need to create a client with tenant Id, Application Id, Client Secret after Authentication.
Is it better to use ADAL  for Authentication Validation rather than MSAL